# SIMPLE jQuery SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1) How to get an alert when I select 1_1.jpg, 1_2.jpg, 1_3.jpg or 2_1.jpg, 2_2.jpg, 2_3.jpg and the other ones arn't selected? (something like this *_1.jpg, *_2.jpg, *_3.jpg)

2) How to randomly position the order of the images (ex: first one: 2_1.jpg, second: 1_5, third:1_9 etc. so only the end of src (*_*.jpg) should differe)?

http://jsfiddle.net/alecstheone/br4bS/

HTML:

```
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_1.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_2.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_3.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_4.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_5.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_6.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_7.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_8.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_9.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/1_10.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/2_1.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/2_2.jpg">
<img class="image" src="../img/Album1/2_3.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:blue;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.selected {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 4px blue; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 4px blue; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 4px blue;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$( ".image" ).click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
  else
      $(this).addClass("selected");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How to get an alert when I select 1_1.jpg, 1_2.jpg, 1_3.jpg or 2_1.jpg, 2_2.jpg, 2_3.jpg and the other ones arn't selected? (something like this *_1.jpg, *_2.jpg, *_3.jpg)

Get your `img` elements in an array `$("img")`, and then condition on both the `src` and `class` attributes in this array.

> 2) How to randomly position the order of the images (ex: first one: 2_1.jpg, second: 1_5, third:1_9 etc. so only the end of src (_.jpg) should differe)?

Get your `img` elements in an array `$("img")`, shuffle that array, and then [append](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) the elements to a container. See [here](http://jsbin.com/oyaxa) for an example.

Comment: I'm very new to jquery may you please modify my jsfiddle a little bit? in 1) I want it to be automate for any *_1, *_2 or *_3 images

Comment: How to condition the src and class in the array?

Answer (score 0):

1) For the selecting, it works like below. It'll give an alert on selecting image 1_1. I think you'll find it not too hard to work with the rest.

```
//If you select any image you get an alert.
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedImgsArr = [];
   $("img").click(function() {
       //alert image name.
       var src = $(this).attr('src');
       if(src="../img/Album1/1_1.jpg") {
           alert("1_1 selected");
       }
   });
});
```

2) You can basically have a function that randomises an array with the image names in them and shuffle it, to print it with JQuery then. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) how to.

Good luck with it!

Comment: But how can I automate this thing to select all *_1, *_2 and *_3 elemnts.. (ex. 1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 2_1, 2_2, 2_3, 3_1, 3_2, 3_3 etc...) Because it doesn;y work with asterix?

Comment: I'd say use a substring. I don't have time to work it all into a total answer though..
`var index = string.indexOf(".jpg");`
`var substring = string.substr(index-2, index);`

That should get the 2 characters before the .jpg extention.